# Open Street Maps with Android Google Maps Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap, google-maps-mobile, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to use an open street map provider with the new Google Maps V2 Api on Android?  If so can you provide an example, or documentation?  I have looked quickly at the docs and found [UrlTileProvider()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider) , so it looks likely this is possible.

Bonus:  Is simply using the MapFragment class with OSM tiles still bound by the Google Maps TOS?

Comment: Just curious as to why you want to use OSM over google maps?

Comment: I'm just restricted by the Google Maps TOS.  My application uses private data, and I can't afford $10,000 /year...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to extend the UrlTileProvider class so you can define the URL for OSM tiled maps and add a tile overlay like that :

```
MyUrlTileProvider mTileProvider = new MyUrlTileProvider(256, 256, mUrl);
mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mTileProvider));
```

With the url for OSM defined like that :

```
String mUrl = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
```

The MyUrlTileProvider class :

```
public class MyUrlTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider {

private String baseUrl;

public MyUrlTileProvider(int width, int height, String url) {
    super(width, height);
    this.baseUrl = url;
}

@Override
public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    try {
        return new URL(baseUrl.replace("{z}", ""+zoom).replace("{x}",""+x).replace("{y}",""+y));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I am now trying to get those tiled maps from OSM with an Offline Mode so if anyone get a quick solution, please let me know!

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on this with a very basic implementation?

Comment: I got the sample up and running with OSM.  Works great.  This with an offline mode would be killer.  Just need to find out about any licensing issues....

Comment: @Patrick Presumably you could write an offline version by implementing TileProvider and providing your own cache to SD? It says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15198767/2209533) that you need to be online when you start the app though for v2. A shame: I'm not sure whether to try that or [osmdroid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13897459/2209533)

Comment: We use osmdroid API since our project start and it works well with online and offline data.

Answer (score 2):

When using this approach, please pay attention to the OSM Tile Usage Policy: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy

Specifically "Heavy use (e.g. distributing an app that uses tiles from openstreetmap.org) is forbidden without prior permission"