# Google map API v2 custom overlay

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, custom-overlay

I am developing an android application for showing the floor map of a building inside google maps. I know there is Google floor plans, but it only available in selected countries. So I need to customize the google map. I am done a little by using the [accepted answer in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles?lq=1). But unfortunately I cant adjust the boundaries of the tiles here, thats not I needed. I only need to show the custom floor map only above the building i need to show, other area should be like the default Google maps. How can I achieve that?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create your tiles? If you draw them on a canvas which is backed by a bitmap just make sure the bitmap is initially transparent. (e.g. bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);)

Answer (score 2):

You could use GroundOverlays, which is a simple image which is shown above the map tiles as you define via geo bounds. See more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay.html)