# Implement MBTiles to GoogleMaps on Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, mbtiles

I have Android application with GoogleMaps map. I was using TileOverlay where I was using tiles from MapBox.
Now I would like to change it and make my application offline available - I created MBTiles using TileMill (MapBox) but I can't find any solution how to implement these tiles into my code.

Comment: There are a lot of example here at stackoverflow if you look around. Perhaps start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles

Comment: Thank you, but this is not for MBTiles... I found this, but it is not working for me https://github.com/cocoahero/android-gmaps-addons

Comment: The project I'm currently working on uses BOTH TileMill to export the custom 256x256 tiles AND the solution linked to above by silver_man. It works just fine, I don't know what you're complaining about.