# What's the url to download map tiles from google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an android app using google maps android sdk v2 and want to allow users to download maps and use them offline.

1. To display the tiles I use a custom TileProvider implementation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles#answer-14833256).
2. **I need to know the URL to download a google maps tile (vector tile if possible) based on latitude, longitude and zoom parameters (e.g. something like [this](http://%20http://mt0.google.com/vt?x=79.84&y=72.32&zoom=16) )**

Before anyone comments that it's violating google maps' terms, I can tell you it's ok to download a small amount of tiles specifically for this use case (see section 10.5.d in their terms [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en#section_10_5)).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the link

http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x=1325&y=3143&z=13

lyrs parameters are :

> y = hybrid
>
> s = satelite
>
> t = train
>
> m = map

By Overriding `getTile` in  your `TileProvider`, You get the needed X and Y and Zoom. there is no need to do anything.

```java
@Override
public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How do you calculate x y z?

Comment: I tested it and it works, so your answer is accepted - thank you @Smartiz. However, when speaking to a local google maps rep he told me using this method to implement offline maps is violating their terms, so I guess I will use a different map provider

Comment: it works great ! as per my requirements , is there any way to download all the map tiles of a region at once ?

Comment: i don't know any method for that. I think you should do it manually. @GurpreetKaur

Comment: Formula to get x,y is:
n = 2 ^ zoom;
xtile = n * ((lon_deg + 180) / 360);
ytile = n * (1 - (log(tan(lat_rad) + sec(lat_rad)) / π)) / 2;

Comment: @drganjoo I'm not getting the expected results out of this formula. What should be the base of the logarithm?

Comment: Got it working! Looks like it's natural logarithm. I made this python [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/tuket/1bc37ee7566d4af3ae14fb4ccbaed083).