# How to use Leaflet in Google Data Studio Community Visualization

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, openlayers, looker-studio

We are building a Google Data Studio Community Visualization and need to draw geographic features on a base map. The Google Data Studio default map component does not support geographic data for example Geojson. To build this feature, I tried Openlayers and Leaflet. Both of them work fine on local env but not Production environment. The error is

```
Refused to load the image 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4093/2723.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive
```

I found [this](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/issues) post by Community Visualization. It seems loading external image, in this case the base map tile, is not a feature of Community Visualization. So, is there anyway to implement a map to Community Visualization?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: If you need a legitimate source which is not external you would be limited to using the Google maps API.  Using an OpenLayers or Leaflet XYZ source configured with the old Google tile url `https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311747/whats-the-url-to-download-map-tiles-from-google-maps might work but using tiles directly would be a violation of terms.

Comment: An important factor to consider is the map size and definition for your project. Since the whole earth have around 30GB data, it will certainly cause problems. But otherwise Leaflet do have the capability to load offline Map layers. If google Data Studio permits load file from local storage it could be a solution. If it does not, you might be able to convert the image as SVGs directly into Javascript code and load them from here.