# Draw Polygon without using connection - Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I wonder if there is some way to draw polygons on Android without using a connection even without showing the map, only drawing the lines.

Currently I can only do this after you have connected at least once on the Internet (probably to validate the key), but I need it completely offline even that does not show the map but only the polygons and lines.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's not possible. Although it's not documented (or at least I haven't found it) Google Maps needs connection to validate the API key the first time you open the map. Then you can use all the functionalities without connection. If this is a must, you can evaluate some alternatives like Open Street Maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom [TileProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) answer with blank tiles and than draw [polygon](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon) as usual.

Comment: but even so, the polygon will only show if I have already connected to the Internet at some point, right?

When I install the application and do not use the internet it only shows the blank screen without the polygon.

Comment: "but even so, the polygon will only show if I have already connected to the Internet at some point, right?" - unfortunately yes. As You wrote GM needs to validate the key.