# How to close a response body when Tile not exists?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I put tiles on top of the map. There are areas where there are no tiles and I get a leak `W/OkHttpClient: A connection to http://*****.***/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?` . How to fix this error? I know about this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles), but I do not know the exact boundaries, so this method does not fit.
 My code:

```
TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
        @Override
        public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            String s = String.format("http://****.***/tiles/%d/%d/%d.png", zoom, x, y);
            if (!checkTileExists(x, y, zoom)) {
                return null;
            }
            try {
                return new URL(s);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }

        private boolean checkTileExists(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            int minZoom = 7;
            int maxZoom = 17;
            if ((zoom < minZoom || zoom > maxZoom)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    tileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
```