# Loading large image into Google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my app i need to make a big map.
I used this code to load image of map to the Google map as a ground overlay.

```
GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions() 
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0), 27000000f, 12735849f)  
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map3));
googleMap.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

However, after several entries to the fragment with the map, i get OOM exception.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 134217740 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 37MB until OOM
```

So, is there any way to load large images to the Google map?

Answer (score 1):

Don't load whole image - use [`TileProvider`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) answer of [Alex Vasilkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687154/alex-vasilkov)

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap you are trying to use is evidently very large. Check out this link from Google that will explain the how and why to load bitmaps in a more efficient manner :
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the thing is that I need to use the full size of my image, so I can not make it smaller.