# Avoid aliasing on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, antialiasing

I am trying to display a custom overlay on a map, using Google Maps for Android, but I am suffering aliasing issues.

This is my code in order to add the overlay:

```
BitmapDescriptor bmd = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .zIndex(1)
    .image(bmd)
    .bearing(rotation)
    .visible(true)
    .positionFromBounds(bounds);
groundOverlay = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlayOptions);
```

I've seen many answers recommending the use of `Paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)` but I don't think this would work for me as long as I am not managing directly how the image is painted

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51178059/6950238) question and comments. For high quality for overlay images you should use [Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay)