# How to put image on google map using groundoverlay in android where image having 5k (width)* 5k (height) and 1.6 mb of size?

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, memory-management, gmsgroundoverlay

I wanna put an image of my city which contains roads and homes on google map using groundoverlay method in android, where my image size and dimensions are very large .
How I can put this image on map in android?

Answer (score 0):

Split your image into `256x256` pixel tiles with e.g [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/) put it in `assets` folder and use tiles like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) answer of [Alex Vasilkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687154/alex-vasilkov):

> ```
> public class CustomMapTileProvider implements TileProvider {
>     private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 256;
>     private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 256;
>     private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
>
>     private AssetManager mAssets;
>
>     public CustomMapTileProvider(AssetManager assets) {
>         mAssets = assets;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
>         byte[] image = readTileImage(x, y, zoom);
>         return image == null ? null : new Tile(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, image);
>     }
>
>     private byte[] readTileImage(int x, int y, int zoom) {
>         InputStream in = null;
>         ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = null;
>
>         try {
>             in = mAssets.open(getTileFilename(x, y, zoom));
>             buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>
>             int nRead;
>             byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
>
>             while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
>                 buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
>             }
>             buffer.flush();
>
>             return buffer.toByteArray();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>             return null;
>         } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>             return null;
>         } finally {
>             if (in != null) try { in.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
>             if (buffer != null) try { buffer.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
>         }
>     }
>
>     private String getTileFilename(int x, int y, int zoom) {
>         return "map/" + zoom + '/' + x + '/' + y + ".png";
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I have only starting and ending lat longs of city then How I will set each tile above city?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary When you create tiles, each tile got name and path into root folder depending on it's [coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates) and zoom level. `TileProvider` converts lat/lng into tile names.