# How to display your own map in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, dictionary

I have a problem. I need to implement something like this https://youtu.be/F16FZyOPOWw.

A very similar. I need to display my own map, need to scroll it, and draw some lines which will shows a distantce in meters. How to implement it, do you know? There are some libraries maybe? Maybe I can change a map from Google Maps to myself? I can't to find some helpful info in the Internet, help please.

Comment: Just a guess. Google use "vector maps", if you have just an image kind of jpeg or png, than I'm almost sure that you'll need write your own "class" with event handlers and do some math depends from scale of image

Comment: @DuhVir so I need to extend some class from Google Maps, or what?

Comment: I'm afraid not. If it was me, than I wrote new class, not extending anything, even ImageView. Just class with `ImageView` and "image file" in constructor and do all calculations in functions. So if it;s not vectors, than you just need "maximum height in meters = image height" and same with width, than "distance between points(x;y coordinates)" - it's simple geometry. And scale factor from image. All by hands. It's just my opinion, try to wait other answers. May be someone already found some github project for it )

Comment: Distance example https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to make an indoor map. how can i accomplish a real map /webview like scrolling in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377660/i-want-to-make-an-indoor-map-how-can-i-accomplish-a-real-map-webview-like-scro)

Comment: @MorrisonChang as I understand, there is no way to create a map as png, only vector graphic. Am I right?

Comment: While you can use vector graphics, I provided links to information about using tiles or images at different zoom levels to achieve a scrollable map effect. Please read through the link sources.