# Trouble with converting PDF to cacheable bitmap

Tags: java, android, pdf, caching, bitmap

I am working with a PDF that is a map of the subway system. The PDF itself is <1 MB. I am trying to get the Android phone to convert to Bitmap when launching the app, so that when the mapfragment is accessed by the user, I can load a cached bitmap that a user can then interact with

I am having an issue where my converted Bitmap is 84 MB and thus (I believe) too big for the cache

My question is what can I do to mitigate this issue. I had a couple of approaches in mind

1. convert the PDF to a PNG outside of the app, and store the PNG as an asset and simply load from that. I am avoiding this approach since the map gets updated frequently and I'd rather quickly drop in a PDF into the project each time that happens
2. convert the PDF to bitmap upon tapping the map fragment but that causes a 1 second or so delay as the PDF gets converted each time the map fragment is accessed
3. convert the PDF to bitmap and save to disk cache, but I am hesitant about frequent writes to the user's disk and negative implications of that

Below is my PDF conversion code

```
private Bitmap convertPdfToBitmap() {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    PdfiumCore pdfiumCore = new PdfiumCore(this);
    try {
        File f = FileUtils.fileFromAsset(this, "mappdf.pdf");
        ParcelFileDescriptor fd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = pdfiumCore.newDocument(fd);
        pdfiumCore.openPage(pdfDocument, 0); // open the first page

        // Create a Bitmap object to hold the content of the page
        int width = pdfiumCore.getPageWidthPoint(pdfDocument, 0) * 3; // I found less than 3 too blurry of an output
        int height = pdfiumCore.getPageHeightPoint(pdfDocument, 0) * 3;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        int bitmapByteCount = bitmap.getByteCount();
        Log.i("RootActivity", "Bitmap byte count: " + bitmapByteCount);

        // Render the page content on the Bitmap object
        pdfiumCore.renderPageBitmap(pdfDocument, bitmap, 0, 0, 0, width, height);

        pdfiumCore.closeDocument(pdfDocument); // remember to close the document

        Log.d("RootActivity", "PDF conversion completed");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("RootActivity", e.toString());
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

And the cache code

```
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
        }
    };

    // Convert PDF to bitmap and add it to cache
    Bitmap bitmap = convertPdfToBitmap();
    addBitmapToMemoryCache("mappdf", bitmap);
```

Comment: While I question how frequently subway/transportation maps change. You state that the map bitmap is so large due to PDF conversion while keeping detail. Be aware that [there are other ways to get map-like behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57377660/295004) but those choices are more like your first option unless you put the map tiles in the cloud for download which would mean that you could update as frequently as you wished without a new app release.

Comment: Do not store a bitmap in the cache but a jpg file. When needed convert jpg to bitmap.

Comment: Further i do not understand the problem as 84 MB is nothing where devices now adays have 4, 6, 8, 12 GB of RAM.