# Google map still loading when animating locations

Tags: flutter, google-maps, animation

I want to animate google map from one place to another. I use following code to do this;

```
final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_endPlace));
```

The animation works fine. But when I move to the new location the map take some time to load at the new location.

Is there a way to pre load the maps needed along the animation path?

Answer (score 0):

Its not about exactly flutter, but one of technically possible way is to use [TileProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) with local preloaded (or loaded in separate threads) tiles files like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) answer. Tiles you can get via URL like that:

[`http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x=91&y=53&z=7`](http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x=91&y=53&z=7)

More about tile coordinates you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates).

Also read carefully [General information](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/) and [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/help/terms_maps/) especially:

> b. copy the content (unless you are otherwise permitted to do so by the
> Using Google Maps, Google Earth, and Street View permissions page or
> applicable intellectual property law, including "fair use");
>
> c. mass download or create bulk feeds of the content (or let anyone else
> do so);

because Google don't allow that. May by [OSMDroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) is better for you.