# Tile Overlay coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing map application from my country, which is meant for people who like to spend time in woods.

So far, i managed to apply WTMS map into google maps, but currently problem is scale and coordinates.

So i want application to be able to show your location from WTMS map, but that isnt going to work, since my countrys map has been scaled to whole world.

I am not sure, how i could fix this.
[Picture from my situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqgb0.png)

Comment: Just do everything like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) if your tiles are stored in local files.

Comment: The provided answer mentioned above does look feasible. If however it doesn't work for you, then please provide a simplified reproduction case (sscce.org) and add it to a git hosting provider (e.g. github, bitbucket, etc). The easiest way to do this might be to fork the Google Maps Android API Samples Repository and modify one of the existing demo activities: github.com/googlemaps/android-samples